# Return only elements with maximum number of ocurrences

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, set

Lets say we have the following structure in Kotlin for example:

```kotlin
val allExams = setOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
val examMap = mutableMapOf<String, Set<String>>()
examMap["1"] = setOf("A","B")
examMap["2"] = setOf("A","B","C")
examMap["3"] = setOf("A","B","C","D")
examMap["4"] = setOf("E")
examMap["5"] = setOf("F")
```

*How can I filter to only maintain in map items with the maximum number of matched elements?*

In the said example i want to remove `examMap["1"]` and `examMap["2"]` because in `examMap["3"]` i have `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` and `"D"` (which is the item with maximum number of matching elements from `allExams`). The `examMap["4"]` and `examMap["5"]` are to be maintained because are the only items on the map that has these values.

So in the end I want to have the map with the following values:

```kotlin
examMap["3"] = setOf("A","B","C","D")
examMap["4"] = setOf("E")
examMap["5"] = setOf("F")
```

Comment: Is `c` actually `examMap`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: if you have another entry `map[6] = [ B, C, X]` will you keep it ?

Comment: No because it has to match elements from allExams

Comment: @user2620925 so if allExams has 'X', you want to keep the map[6] as well?

Comment: @Kent in that case yes

Comment: I don't think your criteria are precise enough. What if it's `examMap["5"] = setOf("A","B","C", "F")`? Do you keep 3 and 5 even though there's overlap between them? What if its `examMap["1"] = setOf("A","B"); examMap["2"] = setOf("D","E"); examMap["3"] = setOf("A","E", "F")`? 3 is bigger than 1 or 2 but you need all three of them to cover all letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the expected result:

```
val result = mutableMapOf<String, Set<String>>()
examMap.toList().sortedByDescending { (_, v) -> v.size }
    .forEach {
        if (result.isEmpty() 
            || result.values.none { rList -> rList.containsAll(it.second) }) {
            result.put(it.first, it.second)
        }
    }
}
```

The Idea is:

- first sort the Sets in the map by the `set.size` descending.Because, the more elements in the set, the better chance it has to cover other sets
- then start from the largest set, check if already picked sets (in `result`) have contained all the elements in the current set, to decide if append it to the `result`

With the given input, the `result` will be:

```
{3=[A, B, C, D], 4=[E], 5=[F]}
```